# How to create a DrawerItem between DrawerScreens in a DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hey lets suppose we got the following:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"             
        drawerContent={props => {
            return (
                <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                    <DrawerItemList {...props} />
                    <DrawerItem label="B"/>
                </DrawerContentScrollView>                        
            )}
        }>
        
        <Drawer.Screen options={{
            drawerLabel: 'A',
            title: ''
            }} name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />            
        
        <Drawer.Screen options={{ 
            drawerLabel: 'C', 
            title: ''
            }} name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />

</Drawer.Navigator>
```

As you can see I got a DrawerItem labeled **B** that I want to be between the screens labeled **A** and **C**, is there a solution for this?